# do-while loop with chars

Tags: c++, validation, input, char

I'm trying to compare a char entered into an array by user input to some ASCII values. The user is supposed to enter 20 test question answers into testAnswers[i] to see if they match the letters A-D (Uppercase, hence toupper). However when the program runs the do-while loop seems to be completely ignored and you can enter pretty much any character with no issue. How would I fix this? Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char testAnswers[20];
    char answers[] = {'A', 'D', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B'};
    int testSize = sizeof(answers) / sizeof(answers[0]);
    
    
    cout << "Enter the student's test scores: ";
    for (int i=0; i<testSize; i++) {
        do {
            cin >> testAnswers[i];
            testAnswers[i] = toupper(testAnswers[i]);
        } while (testAnswers[i] < 'A' && testAnswers[i] > 'D');
    }
    
    for (int i=0; i<testSize; i++)
        cout << testAnswers[i];
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what letter is `< 'A'` and `> 'D'` at the same time?

Comment: As idclev points out, no letter is less than A and greater than D, so the loop will never loop.

Comment: I was basing it off the ASCII values listed here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii

Comment: @JustinMcCown So what number is less than 65 (`A`) and greater than 68 (`D`)? There are none. You are testing if a number is less than 65 and greater than 68. No number qualifies.

Comment: @JustinMcCown You probably meant to write `testAnswers[i] < 'A' || testAnswers[i] > 'D'` as the condition to continue the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether the char has an ASCII value of less than 65 and greater than 68.To check whether the char is a character between A and D you must check if the char has ASCII value greater than equal to 65 and less than equal to 68

```
do
{
    // code statement
}while(testAnswers[i] >= 65 && testAnswers[i] <= 68 );
```

Comment: Almost! But you need to run the loop if the test you give is *not* true: `while (!(testAnswers[i] >= 65 && testAnswers[i] <= 68));`.